# How to create a virtual machine on Azure using a python code?

Tags: python, azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

I am new to using the azure sdk and working with it.
I read quite a few example on how to create a virtual machine but none of them worked for me.

I am getting an error in the sms.add_os_image method prior to creating a virtual machine.
Can a VM be created without that method? what should be used as the media link and image name in that case?

A part of my current erroneous code looks like this:

```
#storage account:
result = sms.create_storage_account(name, desc, label, affinity_group=name)

operation_result = sms.get_operation_status(result.request_id)
print('Operation status: ' + operation_result.status)

result = sms.list_storage_accounts()
for account in result:
print('Service name: ' + account.service_name)
print('Affinity group: ' + account.storage_service_properties.affinity_group)
print('Location: ' + account.storage_service_properties.location)
print('')

#blob service:

storage_response=sms.get_storage_account_keys(name)
print "finished getting primary key " + storage_response.storage_service_keys.primary
account_key = storage_response.storage_service_keys.primary
blob_service = BlobService(account_name=name, account_key=account_key)

#container:

blob_service.create_container('containermaryland13')
target_blob_name = name+'.vhd'
os_image_url='https://{}.blob.core.windows.net/containermaryland13/{}'.format(name, target_blob_name)
image_name = '03f55de797f546a1b29d1b8d66be687a__CoreCLR-x64-Beta5-Linux-PartsUnlimited-Demo-App-201504.29'
sms.add_os_image(label=image_name, media_link=os_image_url, name=image_name, os='Linux')



linux_config = LinuxConfigurationSet(host_name='hostname', user_name='username', user_password='mypassword', disable_ssh_password_authentication=True)
os_hd = OSVirtualHardDisk(source_image_name=image_name, media_link=os_image_url)

sms.create_virtual_machine_deployment(service_name=name,
                                  deployment_name=name,
                                  deployment_slot='production',
                                  label=name,
                                  role_name=name,
                                  system_config=linux_config,
                                  os_virtual_hard_disk=os_hd,
                                  role_size='Small')
                                  """
```

Can someone please help me resolve this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if this image has already in your IMAGES Gallery , you will encounter the error as "Conflict" when you add it repeatedly. So I suggest you check this image whether has registered in your IMAGE Gallery. If your IMAGE Gallery already has the image, you can use its Image name and URL directly. 
Also, I created a project for testing this method:

```
os_image_url='https://**.blob.core.windows.net/communityimages/**-**-**-1.vhd'
image_name = 'ub-13-4-test'
sms.add_os_image(label=image_name, media_link=os_image_url, name=image_name, os='Linux')
```

Before you create VM, you need create a cloud service as container for your VM.
You can see this code:

```
name = 'myvmPython'
location = 'East Asia'
sms.create_hosted_service(service_name=name,
    label=name,
    location=location)
linux_config = LinuxConfigurationSet(host_name=name, user_name='*', user_password='*', disable_ssh_password_authentication=True)
os_hd = OSVirtualHardDisk(source_image_name=image_name, media_link=os_image_url)

sms.create_virtual_machine_deployment(service_name=name,
                                  deployment_name=name,
                                  deployment_slot='production',
                                  label=name,
                                  role_name=name,
                                  system_config=linux_config,
                                  os_virtual_hard_disk=os_hd,
                                  role_size='Small')
```

By the way, I used the Python 2.7. Also, you could share your error message with us for further helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could check your Image whether it is existed from Image Panel, as this picture shown:
[image]
Also, you can add image into Image Gallery:
[image]

If image is in your image repository, you can use its name and URL directly. 
[image]

According to error message, it is mean that your project don't find VHD resource, please check your Blob URL.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering! :)